# How to skip "nan" or blanks in my vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with bunch of "nan" and blank cells and i don't want my for loop to evaluate these as shown below in the image

![image][1]

This is my code below and it's taking all the blank cell values as 0 and messing with my code.

````vb
For j = LBound(ARINC_CHA_DATA_array, 2) To UBound(ARINC_CHA_DATA_array, 2)
    For i = LBound(ARINC_CHA_DATA_array, 1) To UBound(ARINC_CHA_DATA_array, 1)
                
        If ARINC_CHA_DATA_array(i, j) <> "" Or ARINC_CHA_DATA_array(i, j) = "nan" Then GoTo Ravi

...........code
...........code
 
     End If
    
  Ravi:

    Next i

Next j
```[![enter image description here][2]][2]
        


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip2B9.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTDou.png
````

Comment: Im trying to skip my code by using the GOTO function but it's not skipping the blank cells.

Comment: it would be good to see entire code especially part responsible for filling array ARINC_CHA_DATA_array.  If it is not skipping try to convert it to test by using CSTR function. Other options is to check what ASCII code is behind this. You can check that by using ASC(left(ARINC_CHA_DATA_array,1))

Comment: ^^ and also code as is has unpaired orphan End If

Comment: What's the logic behind the `If` statement?

Answer (score 1):

### `Select Case` vs `If...Then...Else` When Looping Through an Array

- Use shorter variable names to make the code more readable.
- `GoTo` is kind of reserved for error-handling and its use can most often be avoided.
- The opposite of `A = B OR C = D` is `A <> B AND C <> D`.
  That is why `Test2` is preferred compared to `Test3` (no need for the `Else` statement).
- All three codes do the same: they read the values from a range into an array, then loop through the elements of the array doing `... code` (at the moment nothing) and write the 'modified' values from the array back to the range.
- **Caution**: If there are formulas in the range, after running this code, they will be replaced with values.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J10")
    Dim Acd As Variant: Acd = rg.Value
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim j As Long, i As Long

    For j = LBound(Acd, 2) To UBound(Acd, 2)
        For i = LBound(Acd, 1) To UBound(Acd, 1)
            Item = Acd(i, j)
            Select Case CStr(Item)
            Case "", "nan"
                ' do nothing
            Case Else
                ' ... code
            
            End Select
        Next i
    Next j
    
    rg.Value = Acd
       
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J10")
    Dim Acd As Variant: Acd = rg.Value
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim j As Long, i As Long

    For j = LBound(Acd, 2) To UBound(Acd, 2)
        For i = LBound(Acd, 1) To UBound(Acd, 1)
            Item = Acd(i, j)
            If CStr(Item) <> "" And CStr(Item) <> "nan" Then
                ' ... code
            
            'Else ' you don't need this
                ' do nothing
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
       
    rg.Value = Acd
       
End Sub

Sub Test3()
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J10")
    Dim Acd As Variant: Acd = rg.Value
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim j As Long, i As Long

    For j = LBound(Acd, 2) To UBound(Acd, 2)
        For i = LBound(Acd, 1) To UBound(Acd, 1)
            Item = Acd(i, j)
            If CStr(Item) = "" Or CStr(Item) = "nan" Then
                ' do nothing
            Else
                ' ... code
            
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
       
    rg.Value = Acd
       
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you i tried all three and doesn't work. I don't understand why my code doesn't like when i try to skip the empty cells. I applied your code with manually removing the empty cells and the my code works. But my goal is to get my code to skip those empty cells.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. Play with the `=` and `<>` signs in `Test2` and `Test3`. Maybe one needs to be `=` and the other needs to be `<>` or maybe both need to be the opposite. Let me know which way is correct so I can fix `Test1`.

Comment: I tired playing with the = and <> signs made them the same and oppsite for test case 2 and 3 but it just won't skip over the blanks. Its taking the blank values as 0 and messing with my output. I even tried isempty function to avoid empty cells but it's not avoiding it. I'm running out of ideas.